# Inter project (class library) communication in .Net

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I have a simple web application project created with Visual Studio MVC template, and a class library project which is referenced in the web project.

Now when the web application calls a method in the class library, which protocol it uses for such communications under the hood? Is it TCP/IP or Named Pipe? And which port it uses?

Comment: if you added a reference it is just a direct CLR call. There is no protocol. THis is all connected inside one process

Comment: your library A is compiled and it has API with its signature. Your MVC (also a library) gets compiled against library A and it resolves signatures of methods called in your MVC. At runtime, both libraries are loaded into AppDomain and live inside a single process, where all the signatures are resolved. `--->`  All the protocols that you're asking about normally mean  inter-process communication.

Comment: Thanks @T.S. It helps. Can you please post this as an answer so that it can be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protocols are normally used for inter-process communication.

Referencing libraries in .NET, is for in-process operations. Your library `A` is compiled and has a public API with its signature (public methods/properties). Your MVC project output (also a library) gets compiled against library `A` and it resolves signatures of all methods called in your MVC library. At runtime, both libraries are loaded into `AppDomain` and live inside a single process, with all the signatures being resolved. This is called *"Early Binding"*

Additionally you can have a *Late Binding*

```
string s = "param";
dynamic x = new SomeClass();
x.SomeMethod(s);
```

In the example above, `SomeMethod` is not resolved during compilation. It will be searched for and resolved at runtime.

Late or early binding are all part of the same process and no protocol is required. But if you have multiple processes and need to communicate between them - then you can use a DB, File, Protocol, Memory Mapped File, etc.